# How to call function over

Tags: c#

I have made a function which can replace the position of the chars if they are standing in my list

Code:

```
   public string NoSimilarChar(string password)
        {
            var listOfSimilarCharacters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                listOfSimilarCharacters.Add("l", "i");
                listOfSimilarCharacters.Add("1", "i");
                listOfSimilarCharacters.Add("O", "0");

            // Iterate through each character
            for (int i = 0; i < password.Length; i++)
            {
                var currentCharacter = password[i].ToString();

                // check if the current char exists in either the key or the value of the list of similar characters
                if (listOfSimilarCharacters.Keys.Contains(currentCharacter) || listOfSimilarCharacters.Values.Contains(currentCharacter)) 
                {
                    currentCharacter = currentCharacter.Remove(currentCharacter.Length - 1, 1) + ",";

                }

            }

             return password;
        }
```

Now i want to know how to load the function NoSimilarChar over when the characters is remove

i thought something like this:

```
 if (listOfSimilarCharacters.Keys.Contains(currentCharacter) || listOfSimilarCharacters.Values.Contains(currentCharacter)) 
                {
                    currentCharacter = currentCharacter.Remove(currentCharacter.Length - 1, 1) + ",";
NoSimilarChar(password);
                }
```

but i think this is not good because he then stays in a loop.

Comment: you want to remove those characters from the password text which are in your 'listOfSimilarCharacters' ??

Comment: Why not just iterate through a `List` of characters and use `String.Remove`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ///for replacing
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in listOfSimilarCharacters)
 {
    password = password.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
 }

 ///for removing
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in listOfSimilarCharacters)
  {
    if (password.IndexOf(item.Key) >= 0)
         password = password.Remove(password.IndexOf(item.Key), 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this simpler one

```
 var charsThatCannotbeinUserPwd = new[] {'1', 'l', 'O', '0', 'i'};

        // Iterate through each character
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < password.Length; i++)
        {
            var currentCharacter = password[i];

            if (!charsThatCannotbeinUserPwd.Any(x => x.Equals(currentCharacter)))
                builder.Append(currentCharacter);

        }

        return builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to remove a set of characters from you password.  If that is the case then you don't need to use a `Dictionary`.  A `Dictionary` would make more sense if you wanted to replace one character with another.  Additionally you do not need to use recursion here.  I believe all you need is an array of the characters you want to remove and a simple loop to remove them.

```
public string NoSimilarChar(string password)
{
    string[] charsToRemove = new  string[] { "l", "i", "1", "0", "O" }
    foreach (string charToRemove in charsToRemove)
    {
        password = password.Replace(charToRemove, "");
    }
    return password;
}
```

FYI: I've defined the array of characters as strings because you will want to replace the character with an empty string and there is no empty character.